# what does "~" mean before a constructor definition in c#?

Tags: c#, syntax

what does "~" mean before a constructor definition in c#?
I can't find the answer on the internet and it's giving me trouble.

I encountered it on line 45 in this file

https://github.com/zeul72/SocketsProgramming/blob/90ff469b7e5f416c80256562ec8e96f282b930b9/EP02%20-%20SocketsProgramming/Shared/Channel.cs

```
 public abstract class Channel<TProtocol, TMessageType> : IDisposable
        where TProtocol : Protocol<TMessageType>, new() {
    
 [...]

 ~Channel( ) => Dispose( false );
 
 [...]

}
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685615/1997232)

Answer (score 2):

This is called the destructor that is the oposite of the constructor.
Destructor is called when GC is destroying/deallocate that memory space.

Comment: oh I understand it is a syntax  for destructor thank you very much for your answer

Comment: In fact, it is called [Finalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors).